# PHP hash('sha512',$x) equivalent in Node.js (Angular2, Ionic2)

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I'm trying to create a SHA512 Hash in Angular2 (Ionic2) witch is similar to the PHP function `hash('sha512')`.

I just tried **crypto-js**, **crypto** and **js-sha512** modules but no matter how it is always a different Hash like in PHP.

I also converted the String into Hex with `toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)` and `toString('hex')` but without success.

In PHP that:

NjAxODkwYWZkODA3MDkzMjgzYWQ1>Y2YwMTA2NGRiNGFlNWE0NTM1OWY3YTExMmJmNGIxNjhi

becomes to that how its right:

> a2ea72e6c572ab957987a946a7a490c4ec93e7d0a7466e71b

but in crypto it becomes to:

> eac7baac918158db69d81432037d2ef5f6327d9030e5d7a

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you the Node.js `crypto` package.

**PHP:**

```php
hash('sha512', 'hello');
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const crypto = require("crypto")
const hash = crypto.createHash("sha512")

hash.update("hello world") // Hash the input
hash.digest("hex")         // Return it as a hex string
```

If you need to run this code in a browser, you can bundle it through browserify or webpack. Those 2 tools will use a polyfill for `crypto`.